# Cannot connect Ubuntu to starbucks wifi network

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, connection

Sometimes the network at Starbucks accepts me automatically with out asking me to accept the terms and conditions, etc. And sometimes when it doesn't accept me, this is what I see.

[image]

Of course, this wouldn't be a problem if the "accept" button would pop up like it does on OSX, or if I knew how to find it...

What I have to do instead is to:

1. reboot
2. initialize OSX
3. try to connect to the internet/click on 'accept' because it pops up autmagically
4. get access to the internet
5. reboot into Ubuntu (which is what I am using to post currently)

What seems to be happening is: the Starbucks network is adding me to the list of allowed users after clicking on the 'accept' button, therefore I can have access after rebooting Ubuntu. 
I don't want to reboot my system 3 times just to connect to the Internet.

If anyone knows a solution to this problem I would appreciate it.

Comment: Just a trivial workaround: You can copy the page you are redirected to as soon as you connect to Starbucks Wifi on OSX, and paste it on the browser in Ubuntu That way you "manually pop-up" the *Accept Terms and Conditons* page.

Comment: Where do you live?

Comment: I live in Canada.  I haven't tried to retrieve the link to the pop up page, but that wouldn't be a good resolution to this problem, since I have to go back to OS x to get the link, and the link might be different for other locations, therefore, its the same as what i do now..

Comment: Some things to try, Another browser (Chrome is a good bet), Try to change the user agent so the browser reports Windows or OSX https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/, perhaps the network does not know Ubuntu? Clear your cache from the browser settings.

Comment: What I want to know is why other operating systems don't have this problem. WTF is wrong with ubuntu to cripple their system.

Comment: http://detectportal.firefox.com/

Answer (score 5):

The issue is it recognises that the WiFi connection is trying to “hijack” the secure connection. It prevents this.

To avoid this, navigate to http://neverssl.com. This webpage will never use HTTPS and family, so it will always be “hijackable” by the WiFi.

Comment: I Have tried many websites to see if it would trigger the "accept" page.. but it doesnt work.

Comment: Including http://btopenzone.com?

Comment: @Tim it may only work for the UK

Comment: @M.Becerra Ahh, yes. In the US they do not specify a trigger url.

Comment: I live in Canada

Comment: Okay, the service is provided by http://www.allstream.com in Canada. You could try that page. Equally, they have a freephone 1-866-385-2555 - they may be able to help.

Comment: Besides manually opening this webpage and being redirected to the *Terms and conditions*, is there a way to have it done automatically the same way it does work on OSX, Win, or many other OS?

Comment: I think firefox uses http://detectportal.firefox.com/

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

YouTube prevents other sites, even your hotspot's login page, from doing anything using its domain name:

1. You're trying to go to YouTube
2. The hotspot is trying to redirect everything you do, including YouTube pages, to its login page until you login
3. YouTube is set up to force your browser to use HTTPS (that's what HSTS in that error message means)
4. HTTPS allows only the genuine YouTube site to work on its domain name
5. The hotspot won't work through YouTube's domain name, getting blocked by the browser just like you see

### Solution

To log into hotspots, use [neverssl.com](http://neverssl.com):

1. Open a new tab or window in your web browser.
2. Go to http://neverssl.com — which prevents the use of HTTPS and allows hotspot to redirect to login page.  (You can add this to your browser bookmarks so you don't forget it).
3. If the hotspot login page doesn't appear, press the reload button
4. Log in to the hotspot
5. Close the tab after successfully logging in

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Ubuntu on a Mac, but I use my Kubuntu laptop in Starbuck's on a weekly basis.  What I do is to manually select the Starbuck's free wifi (labels itself as "Google Wifi"), then open a browser (to any page, in my experience the Starbuck's router will intercept the request) to get the "accept and connect" prompt.  Sometimes, this will fail.  If it does, I just disconnect (if necessary) from the Wifi selection widget, then reconnect and refresh the browser page.

To get to the Wifi controls, I click the tray icon for Wifi (upward cone made of arcs), which pops up the list of available networks.  It should work similarly in your GUI.  I've *never* had to reboot to get connected, even though it does occasionally take two tries to get the browser to bring up the connection page before the Wifi times out (my laptop is about 10 years old).

Comment: thanks for the insight, but i have tried that many times. disconnecting and reconnecting doesnt triger the "accept" page to pop up